# Counting points within polygon using PyQGIS?

Tags: pyqgis, count

I have one polygon and onde shp of points (some within and others without the polygon).
I have tried the following code:

```
layers = QgsProject.instance().mapLayers()

for feature in layers['poly_teste_1'].getFeatures():
    geom_poly=feature.geometry()

for feature2 in layers['points_test2_2'].getFeatures():
    geom_point=feature2.geometry()
i=0
for points in layers['pointo_test2_2'].getFeatures():
    if geom_poly.contains(geom_point):
        i=i+1


print(i)
```

The problem is that the code a printing the total number of points, and not only the ones that are within the polygon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*(in the second loop*) : you assign **geom_point** the geometry of the **last** point found in your point layer (*last of the loop, depending of your table's objects order ...*)

*(In the third loop*) : you 'play' with this **geom_point** which is "**a**" point (obviously in your polygon) but you're not iterating over **all** the points of your point layer.

*That's not a gis issue but a programming issue ...*

Comment: Ok! Now I see that. Thanks.. the if inside the second loop solved the problem

Comment: At least half of questions at SE GIS are then programming issues since people do not know how to write code to get desired result or make mistakes when writing the code.

Answer (score 2):

A simple way can be use the processing algorithms "Select by location", where PREDICATE: [6] means "are within"

```
processing.run("native:selectbylocation", {'INPUT':point_layer,'PREDICATE':[6],'INTERSECT':polygon_layer,'METHOD':0})
point_layer.selectedFeatureCount()
```